# Multiple RewriteCond in a row to redirect subdomains to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code and the only redirect that seems to be working is the first one. I get 500 errors on the other redirects.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1.domain.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://s.domain.com/sub1/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2.domain.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://s.domain.com/sub2/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test3.domain.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://s.domain.com/sub3/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try enabling RewriteLog to see what is causing the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746769/log-of-apache-rewrites

Comment: I would suggest adding a R flag. So `[L]` will become `[L,R]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test(1|2|3)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://s.domain.com/sub%1/$1 [L,R]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You could even use `([0-9]+)` instead of `(1|2|3)`, to match any number.

Comment: @Gerben yes I could have used `([0-9])` or `(\d)` but as mentioned in the question, it looks like there are only `1`,`2`,`3` used in the sub domains. Hence `(1|2|3)`.

Comment: Thanks ThinkingMonkey this seems to work as well but I just used @Gerben solution.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey it was intended as an addition. You were right to stick to the original question, and keeping thinks simple. +1